# Who decides how EU structural funds are distributed?

Tags: european-union

The EU distributes developmental money via structural funds.

How is structural fund allocation decided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is usual for EU legislation, the Regional Policy framework is passed by the European Parliament and the Council (the representation of the member states), based on a proposal by the European Commission. The framework defines which types of projects are eligible, and in which regions (mostly based on their per-capita GDP). The decisions about individual projects are then taken, within the framework, by the member states.

Comment: Thank you. Is the Regional Policy Framework annually decided? And how does it set the eligibility criteria - based on economic factors, or specific policy goals (eg roads)?

Comment: @Ben: Like the EU general budget, it runs for seven years at a time. Current is the 2014–2020 period. (That is also one reason why a Brexit transition phase is planned to run until end of 2020.) The next period, 2021–2027, is currently being planned, and the Commission has made a proposal. [A short press release](http://ec.europa.eu/regional_policy/en/newsroom/news/2018/06/06-08-2018-regional-development-and-cohesion-policy-2021-2027) and [a more detailed fact sheet](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_MEMO-18-3866_en.htm) (with further links) are available on the Commission’s website.

Comment: Thank you. So if I want a new marina in the Outer Hebrides (a real example) then do I put a proposal to the EU, who then review it within the context of the RPF, and then award/or not the funds? Please can you clarify when the member state intervenes?

Comment: @Ben: You as an applicant only have contact with British agencies (which ones I don’t know). They will evaluate the proposal and make a decision, based on an agreement between the UK (or possibly Scotland or some other subdivision) and the EU. The EU is not normally involved in the process of individual applications, it only provides the UK with the funds.

Comment: OK thank you for the clarification. What is the nature of the agreement process between the UK (or Scotland/subdivision/“Managing Authority”) and the EU?

Comment: @Ben: I found a [description of the implementation process](http://ec.europa.eu/regional_policy/index.cfm/en/policy/how/stages-step-by-step/). There is also a [list of existing Operational Programmes](http://ec.europa.eu/regional_policy/en/atlas/programmes/) (by country, plus cross-border ones), including [one for Scotland](http://ec.europa.eu/regional_policy/en/atlas/programmes/2014-2020/united-kingdom/2014uk16rfop004) managed by the Scottish Government.